# Make azure pipeline stage noncancellable

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, pulumi, pulumi-azure

Is there a way to make an azure pipeline stage or job noncancellable?

**Description:**

We have a pipeline in the lines of:

```
stages:
- stage: BuildAndUnitTest
  .........
  .........
- stage: DeployAndTest // deploys to a shared resource and runs tests against it
  lockBehavior: sequential
  jobs:
  - job: DeployInfrastructureUsingPulumi
  .........
  .........
  - job: RunTestsAndCleanUp
  .........
  .........
  - job: DestroyInfrastructureUsingPulumi
  .........
  .........
```

In the pipeline note that `DeployAndTest` stage makes changes to a shared resource. It deploys cloud infrastructure, runs some tests then destroy the infrastructure.

The next run should take place only after the clean and destroy are finished.

- Is there a way to ensure once the pipeline enters the `DeployAndTest` stage it cannot be cancelled manually or due to new push to branch when it runs as part of a pull request build?
- Or is there a better technique to achieve this kind of pipeline run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the condition "[**`always()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions)" to the stages and jobs that you want to be noncancellable.

[image]

For example:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: 'Stage A'
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    displayName: 'Job A1'
    . . .

  - job: A2
    displayName: 'Job A2'
    dependsOn: A1
    condition: always()
    . . .

- stage: B
  displayName: 'Stage B'
  dependsOn: A
  condition: always()
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    displayName: 'Job B1'
    . . .

  - job: B2
    displayName: 'Job B2'
    dependsOn: B1
    . . .
```

- When **`Stage A`** is running, if cancel it, **`Job A2`** and **`Stage B`** will still run.
- When pipeline is running, if cancel the whole pipeline run, **`Job A2`** and **`Stage B`** will still run.

Comment: Hi, just to confirm, these stages wont stop running when new changes are pushed into a branch during pull request build run?

Comment: @dushyantp, Yes. The stages will keep running.